# Sending only textual content with mail function in php

Tags: php

I have read that i must include some headers when using `mail()` function in PHP like:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

but in my case i want only to send text, not html. so are those headers will still be required to make a successful mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers of *mail()* function are optional.
Your email can be delivered successfully, without any header.

Note that some default values will be set. As an example, if you do not declare a sender (*From*), the server name will be used instead.

Comment: Yes. and by declaring no header. it won't go to spam folder because it is missing the headers?

Comment: Good headers can help you to increase the delivery of your emails but not only. Server reputation is also a important criteria.